# How to group by when using a modulo

Tags: postgresql, group-by, modulo, rank, row-number

For each company, I want to **sum** the **revenue** for the 4 most recent quarters, then the 4 subsequent ones, and so on (see screenshot attached for details). How can I do that?
SQL query and result - 1st attempt (failed)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWhhb.png

```
SELECT 
    ticker, 
    period_end_date, 
    revenue,
    1+ ((rn - 1) % 4) AS test
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ticker, 
        period_end_date,
        revenue,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ticker ORDER BY period_end_date DESC) rn
    FROM "ANALYTICS"."vQUARTERLY_MASTER_MATERIALIZED"
    --WHERE ticker = 'ACN'
    ORDER BY ticker
) q
```

EDIT: the following code meets my needs. The 'revenue' is summed using the most recent quarter and the 3 quarters thereafter.

```
SELECT 
    ticker, 
    period_end_date, 
    SUM(revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY ticker ORDER BY period_end_date DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 3 FOLLOWING) AS total_revenue
    FROM "ANALYTICS"."vQUARTERLY_MASTER_MATERIALIZED"
--WHERE ticker = 'ACN'
ORDER BY ticker
```

Comment: use [QUARTER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_quarter) and not modulo....  (If this is about MySQL, which is unclear now..... )

Comment: Does every ticker have exactly one row for every quarter? Or are some rows 'missing' where the revenue would be zero? (If none are missing, just use ROWS 3 PRECEDING AND 4 FOLLOWING in the window function's frame clause).

Comment: "Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL." (see: [SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql)) ==> Please correct the tags!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
SELECT ticker 
     , period_end_date 
     , total_revenue
FROM (
    SELECT ticker 
         , period_end_date
         , SUM(revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY ticker ORDER BY period_end_date DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 3 FOLLOWING) AS total_revenue
         , max(period_end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY ticker) AS period_end_date_max
    FROM "ANALYTICS"."vQUARTERLY_MASTER_MATERIALIZED"
    --WHERE ticker = 'ACN
     ) q
 WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM period_end_date) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM period_end_date_max)
 ORDER BY ticker, period_end_date ASC
```